# Making a link slider effect in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a navbar with multiple links

```
const Navbar = React.memo(() => {
    const [activeLink, setActiveLink] = useState(-1);

    const renderLine = () => {
        if (activeLink !== -1) {
          const linkElements = document.querySelectorAll('.grad-wrap a');
          const activeLinkElement = linkElements[activeLink];
          const position = {
            //@ts-ignore
            left: activeLinkElement.offsetLeft,
            //@ts-ignore
            width: activeLinkElement.offsetWidth,
          };
          return <div className="line" style={position}>;</div>;
        }
        return null;
      };


    return (
        <>
          <nav className="w-full fixed flex">
            <div className="nav-link w-full flex align-center space-between relative">
                <div className="grad-wrap h-full w-full flex align-center space-between relative">
                    <NavLink to="/home" onClick={() => setActiveLink(0)}>Home</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/items" onClick={() => setActiveLink(1)}>Catalogue</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/sell" onClick={() => setActiveLink(2)}>Sell</NavLink>
                    <NavLink to="/about" onClick={() => setActiveLink(3)}>About</NavLink>
                    {renderLine()}
                </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
      
          <Outlet />
        </>
      );
      
});
```

```
nav {
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgb(21,21,21);
    color: white;
    font-size: larger;
}

.grad-wrap {
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gradient-orange), var(--gradient-pink));
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
    color: white;
}

.grad-wrap .line {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    bottom: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    transition: left 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
    background: red;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

}

.nav-link {
    max-width: 700px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 35px;
}

.grad-wrap a {
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.grad-wrap .active, .grad-wrap a:hover {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

all unclicked and unhovered links are white, and they change color to a gradient on hover/click. Underneath the links is a line, which slides to a clicked link.

Now, this line has a red color, but what I'm trying to achieve is to clip is the same way as the text, so that it has the background gradient color that changes when it moves.