# using background-clip: text property with an absolute element

Tags: html, css, text, clip, background-clip

Here I have a clipped text that has a gradient color

```
<div className="gradient"
   <p className="text">gradient text</p>
</div>
```

```
.gradient {
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
    background-clip: text;
}

/* need this to have position: absolute */
.text {
    font-size: 100px;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

I need the text to be an absolute element. How can I achieve the same clipping effect with text having `position: absolute`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Why does the text need to be `absolute`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a navbar with links placed horizontally. The links are wrapped in a div which has a hidden gradient background. The links are clipped so that the text has the color of the gradient (each link is at a different part of the gradient). Now, I want to make an indicator of a clicked link. An underline, which slides below the clicked link. I also want to clip this underline so that its color changes based on position. And well, this slider has an absolute position. I couldn't manage to clip the whole div box, so I'm using UTF-8 characters to simulate the line, which boils down to this problem

Comment: Then I suggest you demo that so we have proper context and current code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77842440/18565217